# Infinitive as a subject in a question

Tags: verbs, to-infinitive

I know I can use an infinitive as subject, but I haven't seen it used in a question. Is it possible?

> Is to take care of your cat easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While to-infinitive can be subjects of sentences, and it is possible to write

> To take care of your cat is easy.

This is not the usual way to express in English.  It is far more common to write:

> It is easy to take care of your cat.

Similarly, while it is not incorrect to form a question "Is to take care of your cat easy?"  Don't do it. It is poor English.

You should use the introductory "it" and delay the subject:

> Is it easy to take care of your cat?

It may be more acceptable if the infinitive phrase is particularly short:

> Is to travel the only thing that she is thinking about now?

But even in this case, it would have been better to use a gerund "Is travelling..."